# how to get sum across rows in a group based on condition in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset:

```
type              month       id1  id2  id3   value 
history           jan-17       1    2    3      10
future            jan-17       1    2    3      15
history           feb          1    2    3      12
history           march        1    2    3      11
future            march        1    2    3      14
```

I want to get value for each month based on some calculation and based on the value of `type` column.

For eg : the output should look like this:

```
month    id1  id2  id3   value
JAN-17   1    2    3     15(future value of jan) + 0(as future value of feb is not present)+ 14(take the future value of march)
FEB-17   1    2    3     10(history value of jan)+14(take the future value of march)
MAR-17   1    2    3     10(history value of jan)+12(history value of feb)+11(history value of mar)
```

The calculation is based on the quarter number of each month in a year.
If it is the first month of a quarter, take the future value of first month + future of 2nd month + future value of 3rd month

If the month is 2nd month of a quarter, take the history value of 1st month + future value of 2nd month + future value of 3rd month

If the month is 3rd month of a quarter, take the history value of 1st month + history value of 2nd month + future value of 3rd month .

I have tried partitioning the dataset based on month `id1`, `id2`, `id3`, but it does not give me the expected result .

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output contradict the rules which you wrote further:

> If it is the first month of a quarter, take the future value of first month + future of 2nd month + future value of 3rd month
>
> If the month is 2nd month of a quarter, take the history value of 1st month + future value of 2nd month + future value of 3rd month
>
> If the month is 3rd month of a quarter, take the history value of 1st month + history value of 2nd month + future value of 3rd month

I implemented these rules, because they have more clear logic and are easier to implement:

```
with t1 as (select 'history' type from dual union all select 'future' type from dual),
     d  as (select add_months(date '2017-01-01', rownum - 1) month, 1 id1, 2 id2, 3 id3 from dual connect by level < 4),
     t2 as (select * from t1, d),
     source (type, month, id1, id2, id3, value) as (
            select 'history', 'jan-17', 1, 2, 3, 10 from dual union all
            select 'future',  'jan-17', 1, 2, 3, 15 from dual union all
            select 'history', 'feb-17', 1, 2, 3, 12 from dual union all
            select 'history', 'mar-17', 1, 2, 3, 11 from dual union all
            select 'future',  'mar-17', 1, 2, 3, 14 from dual)
select to_char(month, 'mon-yy') mon, id1, id2, id3, history, future,
       sum(history) over (partition by to_char(month, 'Q') order by month) - history +
       sum(future) over (partition by to_char(month, 'Q') order by month desc) value
  from (select t2.type, t2.month, nvl(s.id1, t2.id1) id1, nvl(s.id2, t2.id2) id2, nvl(s.id3, t2.id3) id3, nvl(value, 0) value
          from t2 left join source s on s.type = t2.type and s.month = to_char(t2.month, 'mon-yy'))
 pivot (sum(value) for type in ('history' history, 'future' future))
order by month
```

How it works:

- subqueries `t1`, `t2` and `d` are used to generate full list of months and types
- then join them with source data and make a pivot
- calculate running sum of "futures" and "histories" in different directions
- then combine these running sums together minus current history value, what gives us exactly what we need:

  ```
  MON                 ID1        ID2        ID3    HISTORY     FUTURE      VALUE
  ------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
  jan-17                1          2          3         10         15         29 
  feb-17                1          2          3         12          0         24 
  mar-17                1          2          3         11         14         36
  ```

This solution could be applied to any period of time, data will be calculated for each quarter separately.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what to do with id1,id2,id3 so i choose to ignore it, Better you explain the corresponding logic for it. Will it always be the same value for history,future of a particular month?

```
with 
x as
    (select 'hist' type, To_Date('JAN-2017','MON-YYYY') ym , 10 value from dual union all
    select 'future' type, To_Date('JAN-2017','MON-YYYY'), 15 value from dual union all
    select 'future' type, To_Date('FEB-2017','MON-YYYY'), 1 value from dual),
y as
    (select * from x Pivot(Sum(Value) For Type in ('hist' as h,'future' as f))),
    /* Pivot for easy lag,lead query instead of working with rows..*/
z as
    (
        select ym,sum(h) H,sum(f) F from (
            Select y.ym,y.H,y.F from y
            union all
            select add_months(to_Date('01-JAN-2017','DD-MON-YYYY'),rownum-1) ym, 0 H, 0 F 
            from dual connect by rownum <=3 /* depends on how many months you are querying... 
            so this dual adds the corresponding missing 0 records...*/
        ) group by ym
    )
select 
ym,
Case
    When MOD(Extract(Month from YM),3) = 1
    Then F + Lead(F,1) Over(Order by ym) + Lead(F,2) Over(Order by ym)
    When MOD(Extract(Month from YM),3) = 2
    Then Lag(H,1) Over(Order by ym) + F + Lead(F,1) Over(Order by ym)
    When MOD(Extract(Month from YM),3) = 3
    Then Lag(H,2) Over(Order by ym) + Lag(H,1) Over(Order by ym) + F
End Required_Value
from z
```